# Forward console to channel discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to forward my bot's console to a channel in Discord. I assume I would use `process.stdout` to get the console output, and `client.channels.cache.get(id).send()` to send the message, but how do I combine the two and send that to a channel?

Any help is appreciated, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
let console = process.openStdin()
console.addListener("data", res => {
    let info = res.toString().trim().split(/ +/g)
    bot.channels.get(channelidhere).send(info.join(" "));
});
```

Credits To: https://www.youtube.com/c/MenuDocs

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).